# Livewire - Increased time each time doing request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

Every time I do the same action request, the runtime keeps increasing. Is there any way to fix it?

in my blade :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group @error('promotion') has-error @enderror required">
        <label>Promotion</label>
        <select class="full-width" wire:model="promotion" wire:change="select_promotion">
            <option></option>
            @foreach($data_promotion as $data)
            <option value="{{$data->promotion_id}}" {{$promotion==$data->promotion_id?'selected':''}}>{{$data->promotion_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <x-jet-hold wire:loading.class="visible"></x-jet-hold>
        <x-jet-loading wire:loading.class="visible" wire:target="select_group"></x-jet-loading>
    </div>
    @error('promotion')
        <label id="promotion-error" class="error" for="promotion">{{ $message }}</label>
    @enderror
</div>
```

my method :

```
public function select_promotion()
{
        $this->type_proposal_tap = 'normal';
        $this->modal = 0;
        $this->source_budget = 1;
        $promotion = PromotionNames::select('mst_promotion.*','mst_promotion_form.form_field','mst_promotion_form.form_upload')
                                    ->where(['mst_promotion.promotion_id'=>$this->promotion])
                                    ->join('mst_promotion_form','mst_promotion_form.form_id','mst_promotion.form_id')->first();

       ----other code----
}
```

Doing the same thing, i.e. selecting select option and calling **select_promotion()** method, livewire time request keep increasing like this :

[image: First Image]

After searching for a long time, I noticed that the method call performed an unusual execution, so it looks like the same data query is being executed like this:

[image: Second Image]

How to stop it? even i don't have process in method mount() or render()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use both wire directive (model and change) in select element. If you use the property for bind to backend you can get the lifecycle hook of it like

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group @error('promotion') has-error @enderror required">
    <label>Promotion</label>
      <select class="full-width" wire:model="promotion">
        <option></option>
        @foreach($data_promotion as $data)
         <option value="{{$data->promotion_id}}">{{$data->promotion_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
   //............     
</div>

public function updatedPromotion($value)
{
   dd($value);
   $this->select_promotion();
}
```

if you attempt to use the change action you can do this

```
<select class="full-width" wire:change="$emit('select_promotion', $event.target.value)">
        <option></option>
//.......

protected $listeners = [
   'select_promotion'
];

public function select_promotion($value)
{
   $this->promotion = $value;
   //..... the rest of this method
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Its work sir. But I have a problem with my loading component not working <x-jet-loading wire:loading.class="visible" wire:target="select_promotion"></x-jet-loading>

Comment: hey there. please open another question  and add the code related to it to see what could be happening. greetings

Comment: already solve it sir, i keep wire:model="promotion" on select and using wire:target="promotion" on loading component